# Plex on WD and Synology

Tags: nas, synology, plex

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I have two NAS: one WD Cloud and one Synology NAS. I am trying to add the films on the WD NAS to Plex my library on my Synology NAS without moving all of them across. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tbowden

You need to go to the WD My Cloud's Dashboard and navigate the Apps there. You should be able to add and install the Plex App. When it's installed, you should be able to configure it once you sign in and add your library to the WD My Cloud. After the media content has populated, you can view a list and play the content you wish. Here's [an article](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=12949) from our knowledge base that explains the procedure in details.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how you'd be able to do this on your other NAS, though. I'd recommend you to contact their customer support or search their knowledge base.

Hope I was helpful. Good luck! :)